# Deleting Data from DynamoDb Table automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any kind of life retention period concept in DynamoDB.

I mean is there any way such that data inside a table will be deleted after some time like we can set some retention period in S3.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no "retention" setting available in DynamoDB.

You could run a daily/monthly query that uses a date field to filter results, and use that output to determine which Items to delete. This would need to be implemented in your own programming code.

Some users choose to use separate tables to provide ageing. For example, create a separate table for each month. Then, delete old tables once they pass a certain age. However, your software would have to know how to handle multiple tables of data.

Examples:

- [Reference to monthly rotation of tables](http://0x74696d.com/posts/falling-in-and-out-of-love-with-dynamodb-part-ii/)
- [Understand Access Patterns for Time Series Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html)

Comment: Thaks, can you provide me such links where such kind of implementation is done.

Answer (score 19):

DynamoDB has introduced a Time to Live (TTL) feature. You can create a numeric field and set the value to "time in seconds" (since epoch) when you want the record to be deleted.

DynamoDB will automatically delete the record at the specified time. Of course, TTL has to be configured on a per table basis.

You can fnd more details at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html