# DynamoDB: Remove old entries automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We want to have DynamoDb to automatically delete entries which is, like, more than a year old. Is there a setting or common practice to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting Data from DynamoDb Table automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908093/deleting-data-from-dynamodb-table-automatically)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Note: This answer is now somewhat obsolete, since Dynamo has added a TTL setting on their tables.  Please see link in @Sindhu's answer for more information.  Leaving the answer because chronologically splitting Dynamo tables may still be useful.)

There's no way to do this automatically with a setting.  You can create a job that periodically scans your table and deletes old entries-- you have to be careful when doing this, however, since such a job could easily consume all your configured read and write capacity-- you may have to add delays so this job does not bottleneck the rest of your processing.

Another way to approach the same problem is to break up your table into chunks by week or month-- so you might have a separate table for each month.  Then when the data is old enough to be discarded, you just drop the entire table.  This may or may not work for your data access patterns-- but another advantage is you can configure a lot of capacity for your recent data which you are more likely to access, and less capacity on the older tables you won't need as often.

Answer (score 12):

Dynamo DB has added TTL functionality  to delete items automatically .

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-manage-dynamodb-items-using-time-to-live-ttl/